# How to find where a linter is installed in order to work for SublimeLinter in Sublime 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter, linter

So, I have installed `cpplint` in Sublime 3 via the Package Control, in a Windows 8.1 64bits machine.

However, it seems that `cpplint` cannot be found, as discussed in this troubleshooting page:
http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/troubleshooting.html

More specifically, the page says that:

> If the result says that the linter could not be found, that means the linter executable is in a directory which is not in your PATH, and SublimeLinter will not be able to find it. At this point you will have to find out what directory the executable was installed in from the linter’s documentation. Once you find that, you will need to augment your PATH by following the steps in Augmenting PATH below.

However, after hours trying I just can't find the"directory the executable was installed", in order to include in PATH. Yes, I found many questions about this online, but the only ones that have answers are giving solutions to Linux systems.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the sublime editor select Preferences -> Browse Packages

A folder will open listing the installed packages.